# Prediction intervals for location scale model

Tags: probability, prediction, prediction-interval

Regarding the example below from Chapter 3 of A.C. Davison's Statistical Models, I'm wondering why $Q = (Y_+-\bar Y)/S$ depends only on $g$.

[image]

Comment: Try to substitute the expressions for $Y_+$ and $Y_j$  into the expression for Q and observe that $\eta$ and $\tau$ cancel out, leaving Q only a function of $\varepsilon_+$ and $\varepsilon_j$.

Comment: @passerby51 So the density of $Q$ is not necessarily $g$?

Comment: no it is not. The density of Q only depends (and depends only) on the density of $g$, as stated in the text.